# Limit of $\int_{a}^{b}n\left(f(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x))\lambda (dx)$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. Consider also the sequence $n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x))$. I am to show that

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}n\left(f(x+\frac{1}{n}\right) - f(x))\lambda (dx) = f(b) - f(a)$

Where $\lambda$ denotes the Lebesgue measure.

I can see that $\lim_{n\to\infty} n(f(x+\frac{1}{n})-f(x)) = f'(x)$, whenever $f$ is differentiable. However, since $f$ is only continuous, I have no idea how to approach the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: how about the dominated convergence theorem?

Answer (score 4):

\begin{align*}
&\int_{a}^{b}n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))dx\\
&=n\int_{a}^{b}f(x+1/n)dx-n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\\
&=n\int_{a+1/n}^{b+1/n}f(x)dx-n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\\
&=n\int_{a}^{b+1/n}f(x)dx-n\int_{a}^{a+1/n}f(x)dx-n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\\
&=n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx+n\int_{b}^{b+1/n}f(x)dx-n\int_{a}^{a+1/n}f(x)dx-n\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\\
&=n\int_{b}^{b+1/n}f(x)dx-n\int_{a}^{a+1/n}f(x)dx\\
&=f(\eta_{n})-f(\xi_{n})\\
&\rightarrow f(b)-f(a),
\end{align*}
where $b\leq\eta_{n}\leq b+1/n$ and $a\leq\xi_{n}\leq a+1/n$ are chosen by Mean Value Theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite your expression as
\begin{aligned}
n\Big(\int^a_b \big(f(x+\tfrac1n)-f(x)\big)dx\Big)&= n\int^{b+\tfrac1n}_{a+\tfrac1n}f(x)\,dx - n\int^b_af(x)\,dx\\
&=-n\int^{a+\tfrac1n}_af(x)\,dx +n\int^{b+\tfrac1n}_b f(x)\,dx\\
&=f(b)-f(a)- n\int^{a+\tfrac1n}_af(x) -f(a)\,dx +n\int^{b+\tfrac1n}_b f(x)-f(b)\,dx\
\end{aligned}

Use continuity to control $f(x)-f(a)$ between $a\leq x\leq a+\tfrac1n$ and a similar argument for $f(x)-f(b)$ between $b\leq x\leq b+\frac1n$.